# Drupal 6 to 8 upgrade modules

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm upgrading the Drupal 6 project to Drupal 8 using drupal migrate UI module.

I've installed the below modules in Drupal 8 for an upgrade from 6 to 8.

- Nice Menus
- Views Slideshow

But, those are not showing in "MODULES WILL BE UPGRADED" list.

What needs to be done before proceeding for "Perform Upgrade". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that these two modules are currently supported in migration path (they have no migrate plugins as far as I can see). Probably you will have to manually transfer the configuration to D8. Regardings Views migration, you can check this module out: https://www.drupal.org/project/view_migration, but not sure if this will work at all respectively with Views Slideshow.

Comment: Thanks SK for valuable comment.